# ansible, azure-cli, ansible_azcollection_version compatable issues

Tags: azure, ansible, dockerfile, azure-cli, pyvenv

using the ansible=3.3.0, azure-cli=2.15.1, ansible_azcollection_version=1.13.0 creating the docker image and using the ansible-venv-v1.0 with the python major version as 3.7

while running the project relared tasks getting the below error like as below

````
The full traceback is:   
Traceback (most recent call last):    
  File     "/tmp/ansible_azure_rm_networkinterface_info_payload_jjflr0kr/ansible_azure_rm_networkinterface_info_payload.zip/ansible_collections/azure/azcollection/plugins/module_utils/azure_rm_common.py", line 232, in <module>    
    from azure.cli.core.auth.adal_authentication import MSIAuthenticationWrapper    
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.cli.core.auth'     
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "attempts": 5,
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "ad_user": null,
            "adfs_authority_url": null,
            "api_profile": "latest",
            "auth_source": "auto",
            "cert_validation_mode": null,
            "client_id": null,
            "cloud_environment": "AzureCloud",
            "log_mode": null,
            "log_path": null,
            "name": "something",
            "password": null,
            "profile": null,
            "resource_group": "something-rg",
            "secret": null,
            "subscription_id": null,
            "tags": null,
            "tenant": null
        }
    }
}
MSG:
Failed to import the required Python library (ansible[azure] (azure >= 2.0.0)) on runner Python /usr/bin/python3. Please read the module documentation and install it in the appropriate location. If the required library is installed, but Ansible is using the wrong Python interpreter, please consult the documentation on ansible_python_interpreter
PLAY RECAP ***********************
localhost
   ``` `

i tried adding the ansible-galaxy collection install azure.azcollection:1.13.0 after this getting the above error,
PLease help to resolve this issue with soggestions and required compatable veriosns to add
````